# Bow tie shape function

Tags: python

I am trying to code a function which prints out a bow tie like shape of numbers in the range of two through nine. Anything that is not within the range of two through nine should not print out.

For example,

```
 >>> numberBowTie(5)

 1        1
 22      22
 333    333
 4444  4444
 5555555555
 5555555555
 4444  4444
 333    333
 22      22
 1        1
```

Most of the practice problems, I have attempted, I did without any problems but I am having difficulty coding this particular problem. I thought about just hard coding eight different printouts but that was too sloppy. The spacing has to be figured mathematically.

The closes practice problem I did that resembles this problem is

```
def arrowHead(n): 
   for x in range(n+1): 
      print ((' '*n)+(' *'*x))
      n = n - 1
```

but it didn't help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def numberBowTie(num):
    for i in range(num):

        # the idea is to iterate on i and when it's '1' to print only one time '1' 
        # then 2*num - 2 spaces and then to print one time '1' again.
        # now do the same with i=2 only print '2' twice, 2*num - 4 spaces and then '2' twice again
        # or in general:
        #
        # 1) str(i)*i == print a string of the number i -> i times
        # 2) ' '* (2 * (num - i)) == print one space (2 * (num - i)) times
        # 3) do the same as in 1)
        #
        print str(i)*i + ' '* (2 * (num - i)) + str(i)*i 

    for i in range(num):
        # in the second loop we do the exact same calculation only in reverse order
        print str(num-i)*(num-i) + ' '* (2 * i) + str(num-i)*(num-i)


numberBowTie(9)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
1                1
22              22
333            333
4444          4444
55555        55555
666666      666666
7777777    7777777
88888888  88888888
999999999999999999
999999999999999999
88888888  88888888
7777777    7777777
666666      666666
55555        55555
4444          4444
333            333
22              22
1                1
```

**For ssm (in one loop):**

```
def numberBowTie(num):
    part1 = ''
    part2 = ''
    for i in range(num+1):
        part1 = part1 + str(i)*i + ' '* (2 * (num - i)) + str(i)*i +'\n'
        part2 = part2 + str(num-i)*(num-i) + ' '* (2 * i) + str(num-i)*(num-i) + '\n'
    print part1 + part2
```

Comment: I feel dumb for the short amount of time it took you to code it and figure out the math behind it. Also, if you dont mind do you mind explaining what exactly is going on in your code using `#`? And lastly, I believe the number 9's should be connected. I think it is missing two numbers 9's right in the middle but everything else looks perfect.

Comment: @Robben don't feel dumb - it's confusing and I "played" many times with such so I'm kind of used to it... comments added + fixed the space issue (by replacing the commas in the print with `+`)

Comment: Should be possible with one loop. If we start with `x = []` and then do the first loop ... `for i...:  x.append( ... )`. Then we can just `print '\n'.join(x + reverse(x))`

Comment: @ssm see the last part of the answer

Answer (score 1):

```
print('\n'.join(map(lambda i: (' '*2*(9-i)).join([str(i)*i]*2),
                    range(0, 10) + list(reversed(range(10))))))
```

If you like terseness :)

Edit - Here's another one. The idea is to first build just one quadrant of the image, and then reflect it to build the rest.

```
def bowtie(n):

    quadrant = [str(i)*i + " "*(n-i) for i in range(1, n+1)]

    def mirror2(xs):
        mirror = lambda xs: list(xs) + list(reversed(xs))
        return mirror([''.join(mirror(x)) for x in xs])

    return '\n'.join(mirror2(quadrant))
```

[Additional musings here.](https://gist.github.com/chris-martin/bc208ea3340e2fd6532d)

Comment: Added a second implementation that might also be interesting.